# How to check if a key name contains a number/special character for a nested json object without looping keys?

Tags: java, json, regex, talend

I'm trying to check whether a JSON object contains a number/special character in its name, and the JSON object is an array of objects and each object itself a nested JSON object and also some keys has an array of objects.
My scenario is if my JSON object contains a number in its key name, that's an error record so I have to remove or skip those kinds of JSON Object, how can I do.
In Talend, If I have JSON object like following it will throw an error that please provide well-formatted JSON

```
[{"abc":"abcd"},{"def":"abcd"},{"0":"saran"}]
```

Since it has 0 as key talend throws that error.

The following is my Actual JSON object

```
[
{"_id":"5dd71ec4ad611b6464f912eb","dimensions":{"0":"0[object Object]","container":1,"weigth":2,"height":253,"lenght":600,"width":400},"errorLocation":{"location":{"type":"Point","geometry":[]},"addressLines":[],"geocodeScore":0,"cleanScore":0},"execution":{"timer":{"timestamps":[]}}},
{"_id":"5ddb15c42fef196f91d279b1","dimensions":{"container":1,"weigth":2,"height":253,"lenght":600,"width":400},"errorLocation":{"location":{"type":"Point","geometry":[]},"addressLines":[],"geocodeScore":0,"cleanScore":0},"execution":{"timer":{"timestamps":[]}}}
]
```

SO I have tried with JAVA routine
Here is my Java routine code

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.json.*;
public class Carrefour_Data_Remove_Issue {

    /**
     * helloExample: not return value, only print "hello" + message.
     *
     *
     * {talendTypes} String
     *
     * {Category} User Defined
     *
     * {param} string("world") input: The string need to be printed.
     *
     * {example} helloExemple("world") # hello world !.
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public static String jsonInput(String message) throws JSONException {
    //String escapedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message);
    //message = message.trim();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(message);
    JSONArray jsonArrayOutput = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
    {
         JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         //message = objectInArray.toString();
         //System.out.println(isJSONValid(message));
         JSONObject innerObject = objectInArray.getJSONObject("dimensions");
         if(innerObject.has("0")==false)
         {
         jsonArrayOutput.put(objectInArray);  
         }


         //System.out.println(innerObject);
    }
   //System.out.println(jsonArrayOutput);
    message = jsonArrayOutput.toString();
        return message;
    }
    public static boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
        return false;

            // edited, to include @Arthur's comment
            // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use regex instead of parsing the JSON and looping the keys?

Comment: Yes, I Wanna use regex, because there will 2000-5000 records for each input file, and each records having 100-150 columns, So I would like to use regex instead of looping the keys?

Comment: If that's the only reason, using regex will not make it faster. Evaluating the regex _might_ be a bit faster than parsing the JSON, but it's not like "one regex vs. a loop", both appraoches have to read the entire file, and using JSON will be MUCH simpler and safer.

Comment: Can you give any code sample on checking keys names in JSON object using regex? But looping the keys is not recommended for us.

Comment: do you need to ignore an invalid inner key-value pair or a whole record that contains it?

Comment: Whole record it contains.

Comment: Who says that looping the keys is not recommended, and why? You _could_ try just `"\"\d+\""`...

Comment: I'm not saying looping is not recommended since there are lot of columns, it would take much time to execute my Talend job and I need to write lot of code, so I'm considering the maintainability issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
String jsonString = innerObject.toString();
boolean b = jsonString.matches(".*\"(.*\\W+.*)\":.*");
// if (b) smth
// else smth else
```

This regex matches strings with a special character or number which are preceeded by " and followed by ":

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm getting escape character error as compile time error

Comment: My bad, I forgot you had to escape the '\' character when using it with 'W'. Try it out now.